# Node.js: Why does pure black (#000000) get detected as RGB 4, 4, 4?

Tags: node.js, color-thief

I have used node-vibrant, get-image-colors, colorthief, all of them detect #000000 as RGB 4, 4, 4.
 [Image here. Just took a picture of an empty portion of the Command Prompt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0mF2.png)

The code I've provided below finds this as 4, 4, 4 (currently using node-vibrant, but every other package also does the same.)

```
const fs = require('fs')
const gm = require('gm')
var Vibrant = require('node-vibrant')
Vibrant.from('test3.png').getPalette()
  .then((palette) => console.log(palette))
```

The output of this code is:

```
Swatch {
  _rgb: [ 4, 4, 4 ],
  _population: 180,
  _hsl: [ 0, 0, 0.01568627450980392 ]
}
```

How do I fix this?
Thank you for taking the time to see this question.
Also, I am fine if you provide code that involves ColorThief or get-image-colors.

Comment: are you sure the png isn't a very very dark gray? the eye wouldn't know, so I guess my question is how did you create the image?

Comment: The hyperlink states this - "Image here. Just took a picture of an empty portion of the Command Prompt.". I've further confirmed using other tools that this image is #000000.

Comment: a color palette isn't a color picker, it should calculate the colors that should go well with the image as a design, based on the colors in the image.. what do you need from the code? do you want something that would return the average rgb?

Comment: I want to find the most prominent color in an image, properly.

Comment: You have done something wrong because there are 4,641 pixels in your image whereas your output says the population is 180. Maybe you used the wrong image.

Comment: Also, you have called `getPalette()` which seems wrong for an image that isn't palettised... although I am completely unfamiliar with **Vibrant** and may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used get-pixels (what get-image-colors uses itself) and counted the values,
it ends up with an object with the amount of times each color appears, and max is the value that appears most..

this results with:
{"#000000ff":4641,"max":"#000000ff"}
for your file..

this code isn't very generic, but you can adapt it to do whatever you need..

```
getPixels('./assets/black.png', (err, pixels) => {
    const data = pixels.data;
    let mapped = {};
    let max = undefined;
    let keys = Object.keys(pixels.data);
    for(let i=0; i < keys.length;i+=4){
        let key = "#"+data[keys[i]].toString(16).padStart(2, "0")+
                      data[keys[i+1]].toString(16).padStart(2, "0")+
                      data[keys[i+2]].toString(16).padStart(2, "0")+
                      data[keys[i+3]].toString(16).padStart(2, "0");

        if(mapped[key]){
            mapped[key] += 1;
        } else {
             mapped[key] = 1 ;
        }
        if(max == undefined || mapped[key] > mapped[max]){
            max = key;
        }
    }
    mapped["max"] = max;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late response, but this code does in fact work!